# Generate migration that creates table for Laravel jobs queue?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to set up a table in order to asynchronously execute jobs in Laravel. I've already written the job class and can dispatch it. However it is dispatching synchronously.

Following the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues) When I attempt to create the migration with `php artisan queue:table` I receive the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]     
Command "queue:table" is not defined.                             
Did you mean one of these?                                      
queue:failed                                                
queue:work                                                  
queue:restart                                               
queue:listen                                                
queue:retry                                                 
queue:forget                                                
queue:flush
```

I noticed I didn't initially have a queue.php file in the config directory so I added the one from the [repository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/config/queue.php) and changed `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync')` to `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),`;

I also changed `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` to `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` in my .env file.

I'm new to job queues in Laravel so I'm not sure what I'm missing. How can I create the migration to utilize the database queue driver?

UPDATE: 
I wound up just creating a jobs table in the postgres db I'm using for the rest of my data following the structure described in the [Lumen documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues) and using that to store jobs but still curious why the `queue:table` function isn't available.

*Laravel Framework version Lumen (5.3.3) (Laravel Components 5.3.*)*

Comment: Instead of doing it yourself. You can use laravel's Horizon(https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/horizon)  for this prupose. But it will be good if you learn how to use them manually. Update laravek version if you can. 5.3 is too old now

Comment: @TimLewis I have, just used the wrong link, updated.

Comment: No problem; just when I first read your question, that jumped out at me as a red-flag; wrong version, etc. I can see it's not, so maybe has something to do with Lumen vs Laravel?

Comment: @TimLewis good catch either way. Ahh, you might be right about Lumen.

Comment: Just a guess. Afraid I've never used Lumen, but if that function is available, you should be able to mimic the process in your own custom command; would just have to see what the `queue:table` command does and copy to your own.

Answer (score 8):

```
php artisan queue:table
```

this command is right but set the       QUEUE_DRIVER=database in .env file
and also check that in job

```
class TempleteEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
```

implements ShouldQueue is required for create migration

and then php artisan migrate